Concerning some quadratic field extension $[L:\mathbb{C}(u,v)]=2$
In the following question I am actually asking about the answer to this MO question.
First, I will ask it generally, then I will present the question and answer appearing in MO.

A general question: Let $K,L_1,L_2,M$ be four fields of characteristic zero, such that $K \subseteq L_i \subseteq M$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$,
and assume that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are isomorphic.
Then, $[L_1:K]=n$ if and only if $[L_2:K]=n$, where $n \geq 1$ or $n=\infty$.


Here $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.
Theorem: Let $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$, $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
Assume that for every monomial $x^iy^j$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$ (except the case $i=j=0$, for which we assume nothing), we have $\mathbb{C}(u,v,x^iy^j)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Then $R=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : R]=2$.
Proof, taken from the above quoted MO question:
Start with $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ and consider its quadratic extension $L=R(\sqrt{u})=R(s)=\mathbb{C}(s,v)$ with $s^2=u$.
Take an element $z$ of $L$, viewed as a rational function $z(s,v)$. Then $R(z)=L$ iff $z\notin R$ (because $[L:R]=2$) iff $\sigma(z)\neq z$ where $\sigma(z)$ is the $\mathrm{Gal}(L/R)$-conjugate of $z$ which is $z(-s,v)$.
We can also view $L$ as $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ in many different ways; let us pick
$$x=s+v, \quad y=s+2v.$$
For $i, j\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x^i y^j=
(s+v)^i (s+2v)^j$ and $\sigma(x^i y^j)=
(-s+v)^i (-s+2v)^j$. If $(i,j)\neq(0,0)$ these are always different, so $x^i y^j\notin R$ and thus $R(x^i y^j)=L$.

Specific questions:
(1) Why we can view $L$ as $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$?
(2) If indeed $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, why the field dimensions are the same; perhaps this gives an answer.

Any comments are welcome! Thank you.
